# Can I move Visual Studio project templates out of the "Other Languages" category?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, but I've seen this behavior in 2015, and I think older versions too.  When I installed VS, I selected the "C# Developer" profile, which I think is responsible for this behavior.

In the "New Project" window, in the Installed > Templates section, I have a C# section, a TypeScript section, but then all other languages are grouped into "Other Languages".  Can I move languages like F# and VB up to the top level, with C# and TypeScript?

[image]

Comment: I don't think so. You're right, this is dependent on which profile you selected. I can't remember what it does if you pick the generic option.

Answer (score 0):

STEPS

1. In Visual Studio, click on "Tools" and click "Import and Export Settings"
2. 2 - Select "Reset all settings" and Click "Next"
3. If you want to save all of your settings select - "Yes, save my current 
   settings" or if you want to **NOT** save your settings select "No, just reset my settings, overwriting my current settings"
4. Select "General" and click "Finish"
5. And click close!